# Get Title of clicked menu-li

Tags: angularjs

how can I get the title of the clicked list element? Unfortunately, the following snippet returns an 'undefined'

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="menuLink" ng-click="menuClick()" title="Cardiology: Test 1"><span>Echocardiogram</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="menuLink" ng-click="menuClick()" title="Cardiology: Test 2"><span>Echocardiogram</span></a>
    </li>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.menuClick = function(linkTitle) {
    var linkText = angular.element(linkTitle).data('title');
    console.log(linkText); 
};
```

Comment: Angularise your code: store your menu items in a `$scope` variable, use `ngRepeat` to show the `<li>` items and pass the corresponding variable to your `menuClick()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution.  First you should angularise your code by storing your menu items in a scope variable.  You can then use ng-repeat to iterate through your items.  You can store the corresponding title as well and then reference that title through your ng-click.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
        <li ng-repeat="item in listItems"> 
            <a href="#" ng-attr-title="item.title" ng-click="getTitle(item.title)">
                <span>{{ item.name }}</span>    
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.listItems = [{
        "name": "Echocardiogram",
            "title": "Cardiology: Test 1"
    }, {
        "name": "Echocardiogram",
            "title": "Cardiology: Test 2"
    }];

    $scope.getTitle = function (title) {
        alert(title);
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/6923/)

Comment: yw... I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use the click event. And reference the target element (`<a>`) and read it's `title` propery.

Html:

```
<a href="#" class="menuLink" ng-click="menuClick($event)" title="Cardiology: Test 1">
```

Controller :

```
$scope.menuLink =function (event){
    var title = angular.element (event.target).attr ('title');
}
```